# How to open the options menu without using the mouse in windowed mode?

Tags: league-of-legends

I put my game on window mode instead of full-screen. Now I cannot reach the options menu any more by mouse (it is too far down) nor can I regain full screen.
Is there any shortcut key combination to open the options menu or any way to change that in the settings?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: may be `alt+enter?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Alt + Enter keys to switch from window to full screen mode and vice versa.

You can also use the escape (ESC) key to open the option menu.